# Comparing the colour of two cell ranges [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

wondering if anyone can help.

I'm a CS teacher and as a part of my current Y10 scheme we're looking at how images are represented by binary. I've created a file that encourages the user to recreate some pixel art based on the binary code provided.

However - now this is where I'm completely stuck - I'm trying to create a macro that allows the user to check whether their colours match what the final result will be. I understand how to compare the two colours, but getting it to work in the large range I have is where it's falling down.
The code I've got so far is:

```
Function Inc(ByRef i As Long)
    i = i + 1
End Function


Sub CompareCellColors()
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Set Rng1 = Range("C1:O19")
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Set Rng2 = Range("AC1:AO19")
    Dim x As Long
    x = 0

    For Each c1 In Rng1
        For Each c2 In Rng2
            If c1.Interior.ColorIndex = c2.Interior.ColorIndex Then
                Inc x
            End If
        Next c2
    Next c1

    If x = 247 Then
        Range("A3").Value = True
    Else
        Range("A3").Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I've included my attempt at a workaround (incrementing a variable if they match) but this doesn't work either.

The program compiles and runs, but doesn't accurately compare the two cell ranges (hopefully that explanation makes sense!). The current result of the x increment is 61009, however the selection only has 247 cells.

Comment: You need to un-nest the two loops and use row-column indexing.  Your code currently compares every cell in `Rng1` with every cell in `Rng2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing every pixel in `Rng1` to every pixel in `Rng2` because the loops are nested. I believe what you want is to compare on a more one-to-one basis. Try instead

```
For a = 1 to 19 'rows
    for b = 3 to 13 'columns
        If Cells(a, b).Interior.ColorIndex = Cells(a, b + 29).Interior.ColorIndex Then
            Inc x
        End If
    Next b
Next a
```

Comment: Thanks very much. However, a couple of things which I noticed.. 

The second for loop is actually for b = 13 to 15, and then later the line is Cells(a,b + 26).
Otherwise, this is exactly what I needed. My VBA knowledge is _very_ rusty so I appreciate the help.